# dynamically bind input value to select list by its JSON data 'id'

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with some fairly complicated data (simplified somewhat below). Here I have a list of selector lists, each with an `id` specified in its JSON data. I then have a list of texts which need to bind a specified field (I've got that bit sorted) in a specified (via the text's `listid`) selector list (haven't got that bit sorted).

This is what my data in the js controller file looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.selectorLists=[
        {
            'id': 3,
            'name': 'SelectionList ABC',
            'rows': [
                {'id':5, 'name':'ABCrow 5', 'Afield1': 'ABCrow5field1', 'Afield2': 'ABCrow5field2'}, 
                {'id':9, 'name':'ABCrow 9', 'Afield1': 'ABCrow9field1', 'Afield2': 'ABCrow9field2'}
             ]
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'name': 'SelectionList XYZ',
            'rows': [
                {'id':1, 'name':'XYZrow 1', 'Xfield1': 'XYZrow1field1', 'Xfield2': 'XYZrow1field2'}, 
                {'id':2, 'name':'XYZrow 2', 'Xfield1': 'XYZrow2field1', 'Xfield2': 'XYZrow2field2'}
             ]
        }
    ];

    $scope.texts=[
        {'id': 453,
         'name': 'Input Text1',
         'listid': 3,
         'listrowid': 9,
         'listfieldname': 'Afield1'
        },
        {'id': 454,
         'name': 'Input Text2',
         'listid': 5,
         'listrowid': 2,
         'listfieldname': 'Xfield2'
        }
    ];

});
```

And this is what the html looks like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat='selectionList in selectorLists'>
        <label for="ddl{{selectionList.id}}">{{selectionList.name}}:</label>
        <select id="ddl{{selectionList.id}}" ng-model="selectionList.selectedRow"                 
                ng-options="row as row.name for row in selectionList.rows" ></select>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat='text in texts'>
        <label for='txt{{text.id}}'>{{text.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' value='{{selectorLists[id=text.listid].selectedRow[text.listfieldname]}}'   />
    </div>

</div>
```

I can use a `$filter` in my controller and get the right list there, but I need to get it to bind its selected value to my text input (by passing in `text.listid`).

```
    var listid = 5;
    var result = $filter('filter')($scope.selectorLists, {id:listid})[0];
```

I also need to be able to initialise a selected value in the selector lists, either by cycling through my texts and coming across the first `listid` that references the list, *and* has a `listrowid` set (i.e. to any value > 0; 0 defines none is selected for that text), or by doing that server-side and just setting a `selectedRowId` (or, better yet, set the `selectedRow`) in each selector list. I'm just not sure how to use either way to set the selected item in the html `select` objects.

As I'm completely new to angularjs, just a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Oh, yes, and [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0ju8vqe/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've found a fairly basic javascript-based solution, but would be really happy to see/use a more angularjs one if anyone has any pointers.

So, added these to my controller (yes, a bit of repeated code so I'd definitely refactor this):

```
    $scope.getSelectedValue = function(selectorListId, fieldname) {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selectorLists.length; i < len; i++) {
          if ($scope.selectorLists[i].id === selectorListId) {
            return $scope.selectorLists[i].selectedRow[fieldname];
          }
        }
    };
    $scope.getSelectedRow = function(selectorList) {
        for (var i = 0, len = selectorList.rows.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (selectorList.rows[i].id === selectorList.selectedRowId) {
            return selectorList.rows[i];
          }
        }
    };     

    //will add selectedRowid server-side so now I just iterate over the selectorLists and
    //then call the function that iterates over the rows looking for the right id
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selectorLists.length; i < len; i++) {
        $scope.selectorLists[i].selectedRow = $scope.getSelectedRow($scope.selectorLists[i]);
    }
```

And from my input I now call the first function with `value='{{getSelectedValue(text.listid, text.listfieldname)}}'`

The [full jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/e0ju8vqe/8/).

**Update**

Refactored for a bit of code re-use and I've now got in my js controller file:

```
    $scope.getById = function(items, id) {
         for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (items[i].id === id) {
            return items[i];
          }
        }       
    }


    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.selectorLists.length; i < len; i++) {
        $scope.selectorLists[i].selectedRow = $scope.getById($scope.selectorLists[i].rows, $scope.selectorLists[i].selectedRowId);
    }
```

And the input value is now set with `value='{{getById(selectorLists, text.listid).selectedRow[text.listfieldname]}}'`, and [here's the latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0ju8vqe/9/).